# Module Error: Cannot find module 'sass' REACT

Tags: reactjs, sass, node-sass

I'm building a react app using sass

I wrote to terminal:

```
npx create-react-app .
```

then I wrote

```
    npm install -g sass



    Require stack:
    - D:\intern\neo\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\utils.js
    - D:\intern\neo\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js
    - D:\intern\neo\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\cjs.js
    - D:\intern\neo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
    - D:\intern\neo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
    - D:\intern\neo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
    - D:\intern\neo\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
    - D:\intern\neo\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
    - D:\intern\neo\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a problem with the project *(D:\intern\neo)* configuration.

If you want to install `sass` globally, go to the terminal and then run the command `npm i -g sass` with administrator privilege.

If the package is installed properly, go to your `neo` project remove `node_modules` dir and `package-lock.json` file and then run `npm i` within the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install node-sass instead of sass. Run the following commands and it should fix the issue

```
npm uninstall sass
npm install node-sass
```

Also, it won't harm to see if your sass-loader needs to be updated

```
npm install sass-loader@latest
```